# WriteFile returns invalid handle

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, io

I am attempting to use Windows WriteFile API as follows:

```
class FileWriter
{
public:
    FileWriter(const std::string & path);
    ~FileWriter();
    bool write(unsigned char * buffer, int num_bytes, unsigned __int64 offset);

private:
    HANDLE                  file_h;
};
```

The implementation is simple as:

```
FileWriter::FileWriter(const std::string & path)
{
    file_h = CreateFileA(path.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

    if (file_h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open the output file");
    }
}

FileWriter::~FileWriter()
{
    if (file_h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        CloseHandle(file_h);
    }
}

bool FileWriter::write(unsigned char * buffer, int num_bytes,
    unsigned __int64 offset)
{
    if (file_h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && buffer) {
        OVERLAPPED overlapped;
        overlapped.Offset = offset & 0xFFFFFFFF;
        overlapped.OffsetHigh = offset >> 32;

        BOOL e = WriteFile(file_h, buffer, num_bytes, 
            0, &overlapped);
        DWORD c = GetLastError();

        LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
        size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, c, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

        std::string message(messageBuffer, size);

        //Free the buffer.
        LocalFree(messageBuffer);

        if (e == FALSE && c == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if ((e == TRUE) && (c == ERROR_SUCCESS))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This always fails with `The handle is invalid` error. However, the file handle is always valid. I even check for it. So, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: To be wrong may be your `OVERLAPPED` structure. I don't see `hEvent` anywhere in your code and if you're building in release it may contain any random value. I always suggest to `memset()` Win32 structures. Yes it's a _waste_ when not required  but it helps me both in debugging and in cases like this

Comment: ahhhhhhh...Looks like I did not understand how this OVERLAPPED bit works. I will look into the docs in more detail and update

Comment: Yes, if you use overlapped, you need to set an event into the overlapped instance. And then wait for it to trigger once you want to know if the writing is done. The members of overlapped you set are not really inputs to a ``WriteFile()`` call - they are "state"... useful once the operation has completed.

Comment: That was it. I needed to create: overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

Comment: @Luca: You'd better just not use the asynchronous write feature.

Comment: `CreateFileA`? `FormatMessageA`? One of these is a minor annoyance. The other a fatal bug waiting to happen.

Comment: The `FormatMessageA` was just something I wrote to get the message behind the id. I will not leave that lying about

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Can you elaborate? I do not read async writes but I need something like the `pwrite` command on posix so that I can specify the offset where to write.

Comment: @Luca: There's [`SetFilePointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541(v=vs.85).aspx) to seek to a specified position before writing.

Comment: I might as well just use `fseek` and be done with it!

Comment: @Luca: Except, `fseek` won't work for files larger then 2GB.

Comment: That is a good point as well!

Comment: @Luca: You can use `_fseeki64()` for files > 2GB.  But since this is C++, you shouldn't be using `FILE*` APIs at all. If you are not going to use the Win32 API, then at least use `std::ofstream` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the tip. Yes, I need to look at how this is wrapped in the c++ libs.